# iOS Autolayout relative to the sibling UIViews programatically

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to add 3 custom views (redView, greenView, yellowView) inside a container view (C1) such that all the custom views (redView, greenView, yellowView) are below each other using Auto layout constraints programatically. I want the container view (C1) to get the same size as the size of it subview, so the output should be like this. 
[image]

The red, green and yellow views are just to show the expected result. Actually the custom view i have is like this.

[image]

I am using Auto Layout to do this. Here is my code to do this. RatingsSingleView is my custom view which are shown in the above image.

```
    @interface ViewController ()

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *ratingsContainerView;

    @end

    @implementation ViewController



        - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView *previousTopView = self.ratingsContainerView;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        RatingsSingleView *view = [[RatingsSingleView alloc] init];
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.ratingsContainerView addSubview:view];
        NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = nil;
        if(i == 0) {
            // Making the first subview top aligned to the container View top 
            topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousTopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];
        } else{
                    // Making the second and third subview top aligned to the view above it
            topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousTopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.ratingsContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];

        NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.ratingsContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];


        [self.ratingsContainerView addConstraint:topConstraint];
        [self.ratingsContainerView addConstraint:leftConstraint];
        [self.ratingsContainerView addConstraint:rightConstraint];


        if(i == 2) {
            // Adding last subview bottom to the container View bottom
            NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.ratingsContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-10.0];
             [self.ratingsContainerView addConstraint:bottomConstraint];

        }
        previousTopView = view;

    }
}
@end
```

So the issue is i am not getting the expected result. I am pinned the container view to the left and right edges and set its height to 0 in the storyboard. once i run the above code i am getting the following result.

[image]

Can some body could guide me what i am doing wrong here. thanks

Comment: so what is the issue ?

Comment: This can be done much simpler with VFL

Comment: I am not very familier with VFL, could you give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

You have given some wrong constraints and I've corrected it try this...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView *previousTopView = self.ratingsContainerView;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        RatingsSingleView *view = [[RatingsSingleView alloc] init];
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.ratingsContainerView addSubview:view];
        NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = nil;
        if(i == 0) {
            // Making the first subview top aligned to the container View top 
            topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousTopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];
        } else{
                // Making the second and third subview top aligned to the view above it
            topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousTopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.ratingsContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];

        NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.ratingsContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];


        [self.ratingsContainerView addConstraint:topConstraint];
        [self.ratingsContainerView addConstraint:leftConstraint];
        [self.ratingsContainerView addConstraint:rightConstraint];

        if(i == 2) {
            // Adding last subview bottom to the container View bottom
            NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.ratingsContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0];
            [self.ratingsContainerView addConstraint:bottomConstraint];

        }
        previousTopView = view;

}
```

Comment: Still not working. I know that you corrected my top constraint for the second and third view, but i accidentally put both items to the bottom. Originally i am doing that correctly.